# Trying to rename files to remove hyphens, file cannot be found error

Tags: python, pandas, file-rename

I am working on locating a file which has hyphens(eg., Hours-2021.xml).When I perform the character replacement, I then get an error that the file cannot be found. If I simply use a filname without hyphens it works as expected. I had found on another thread a solution to reformat the filename and it doesnt appear to work. Most likely it is a simple fix that is eluding me. Here is a sample of my code...

```
import os
import os.path
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd


in_file = input('Enter filename to use:')

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.startswith(in_file):
        new_fn=file.replace('-','')
        new_1 = os.rename(file, new_fn)
        
       
    try:
        xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(new_1)
        xlWbk.SaveAs(r"hours_conv.xlsx", 51)

        xlWbk.Close(True)
        xlApp.Quit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        xlWbk = None; xlApp = None
        del xlWbk; del xlApp

    # READ EXCEL FILE
    output_df = pd.read_excel(r"hours_conv.xlsx", skiprows = 3)



    print(output_df)
```

Everything before the try:   I can get an output that I expect (eg., Hours2021). Then Further I get the error that in this case ""Sorry, we couldn't find Hours2021.xml ..."

Comment: I actually doubt that it works with file names without hyphens. `os.rename()` does not return anything, so `new_1` (consider picking a more descriptive variable name btw) is `None`. Then you pass this `None` value in `xlApp.Workbooks.Open(new_1)`, or if a file with the input name wasn't found, you're referencing an unbound variable that has never been assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without delving too deep in your code, it looks like you have an indentation problem.  Your try-except-finally block should probably be indented to be under the `if file.startswith` line.

Plus, you should probably check that `new_fn` is not the same as `new_1` before doing the os.rename(). Or alternatively you can make the call conditional, like changing:

```
if file.startswith(in_file):
```

to:

```
if file.startswith(in_file) and '-' in file:
```

or something along those lines.

Also, os.rename() does not return a value. So `new_1` gets set to `None`.

Lastly, keep in mind that each time you run your program, it is renaming files. So you may have to rename them back before each run.

Also, keep in mind that your:

```
xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(new_1)
```

will probably always fail, since new_1 is None.

Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, here is a working version of your code. In addition to the above comments, it also addresses path issues, since Excel wants to know the full path of the doc to work with. The working code is as follows:

```
import os.path
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

cwd = os.getcwd()
print(f"{cwd=}")

out_filename = "hours_conv.xlsx"

in_file = input('Enter filename (starting string) to use: ')

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.startswith(in_file):
        new_fn = file.replace('-','')
        if new_fn != file:
            os.rename(file, new_fn)
        # indent
        try:
            xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
            xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(f"{cwd}/{new_fn}") # mod to be new_fn
            xlWbk.SaveAs(f"{cwd}/{out_filename}", 51)

            xlWbk.Close(True)
            xlApp.Quit()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        finally:
            xlWbk = xlApp = None
            del xlWbk; del xlApp

# READ EXCEL FILE
if os.path.exists(f"{cwd}/{out_filename}"):
    output_df = pd.read_excel(f"{cwd}/{out_filename}", skiprows = 3)
    print(output_df)
else:
    print(f"Output file {cwd}/{out_filename} Not Found")
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked. I guess I got a little ahead of myself.